# Firebase - Exclude some screen for tracking

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I have a react native app for android and iOS. Im using Firebase for the analytics. I understand Firebase automatically tracks the screens and this is gives me some headaches. 
Below is the result I see in my dashboard.

[image]

[image]

You could see that MainActivity has a very big value. This screen is just supposed to be a holder right? It means they are always there and should not track them. The correct screens to be track are those react native components screens.

How do I disable or exclude these kind of screens and just track the ones that I need to?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an option to choose which activity to track or vice-versa. but I guess if you disable auto-init of firebase and instead initialize it when you need (for example in every activity you want to track) just call `.init(activity)` in that activity. I'm not sure if there is a better option or even this is going to work